# How to convert Ulong to Lptstr in C

Tags: c, winapi, kernel, ulong

I have an ulong value, how can i convert it to LPTSTR? I need to get LPTSTR value. (no printf)

Example code:

```
ULONG value = 1;
LPTSTR valueString = ???
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is such a basic question that the expected answer must be unintuitive.  Use MAKEINTRESOURCE.

Comment: You only tagged your question as C but C has neither `ULONG` nor `LPTSTR`. You should tag it with whatever API this is from. All the world is not a VAX, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the [`_itoa()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0we9x30h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) family of functions or [`StringCchPrintf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647541%28VS.85%29.aspx). The links go to the 'safe' versions of the functions, but the winapi also provides 'unsafe' and leagacy variants.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply convert it. C just isn't so friendly.

You need to:
1. Get a large enough TCHAR array, where' you'd put the number. You can use a simple array on the stack (but it depends on what you want to do with it).
2. Convert the number to a printable representation in the buffer. `_sntprintf` can do this.
3. Use the address of this buffer.

Comment: Yes, except that if you want to do it properly, you'll need to use something like `_sntprintf` to accommodate the different types of `TCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks @MrLister, the Windows types can drive you crazy. I tried to figure it out, and it seemed like `TCHAR`=`char`, but I guess not always.

Comment: That's right, not always. You have `CHAR` which is 8 bits, `WCHAR` which is 16 bits, and `TCHAR` which can be either, depending on the value of `_UNICODE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itoa` function, which is much simpler than sprintf, but may not be available in kernel.

If `itoa` is not available, you can recode it: [itoa in GCC](http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/itoa.html)